# Upload files from phone intent

Tags: android, android-intent, upload, startactivityforresult

I've an android application where in an activity the user chooses a picture from the phone's memory to upload it to the server using the Action Pick intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

However; now the requirements has changed and the client wants to upload any file with any extension, what intent should I use in order to open the phone's memory **(like the file manager)** and choose whatever I want?

Now I'm using the Get content intent thanks to you guys:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

but the problem is in the start activity for result

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Log.d("select pivture", "passed her");
            Uri selectedMediaUri = data.getData();

            String Fpath = selectedMediaUri.getPath();

            Log.d("Fpath", Fpath);
}
```

I get as follows:

```
/document/primary:Download/tool208.pdf
```

Which is not what I want, I want path like this one:

```
/external/images/media/6634
```

Comment: check this link. http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/

Comment: you can make it as Uri.

Comment: Uri.parse(filePath).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

**UPDATE**

```
   @Override  
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
   {  
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
         if(requestCode==PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE){  
         }  
 }
```

Comment: Note: your phone must have any external file explorer app.

Comment: i cant choose pdf files why?

Comment: `file/*` is not a valid MIME type. Use `*/*`.

Comment: can you the on activity result code so that i can retrieve the path of the file chosen please?