# browsing folder and uploading file firebase

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to allow the user to browse for a video and upload it to firebase storage but looking at the example provided I'm not sure how to get from specifying the file to allowing the user to choose. The example provided is:

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"));
StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);
```

I use ACTION_GET_CONTENT to open a file browser for the user but how do I get the file path and replace the initial line?

Answer (score 0):

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), YOUR_DIR_NAME);

 if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "dir not exists and created first time");
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "dir exists");
 }

String absPath = dir.getAbsoultePath();

Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(absPath + "rivers.jpg"));
```

Comment: you've included +rivers.jpg which is what I'm trying to not do, I wan't them to be able to pick any video file to upload

Comment: @L2C if you want them to be able to pick any video, use Intent for uploading file https://stackoverflow.com/a/41332059/6352712